# Changing H4 Tags from Footer and Widgets into Paragraph Text

Tags: php, header, widget, tags, footer

I've trying to change the H4 tags from my Footer and Widgets on the WordPress site https://www.thebitesizedbackpacker.com/ into paragraph text, using functions.php.

I tried several codes (implemented through Code Snippets), but no success so far.
I came up with the following base code, but with my limited PHP-knowlegde I could use some help in making this work.

Hope someone can help!

**CODE:**

```
add_filter( 'generate_start_widget_title', 'widget_title_start_tag' );
function widget_title_start_tag()
{ 
    return '<span class="widget-title">';
}

add_filter( 'generate_end_widget_title', 'widget_title_end_tag' );
function widget_title_end_tag()
{ 
    return '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a job for css, rather than writing code. If you redefine the appearance of H4 tags in that context, you don't have to muck with how they are generated.

Comment: Hi Jerry, the goals is not to change the appearance of the text, but to change the HTML tag to something other than an H* tag for SEO purposes.